HTTP ERROR 429 at MyApps page Facebook Developers
Yesterday, I was deleting my older apps in Facebook Developer platform. And suddenly I got HTTP error 429. I guess it is because I deleted so much app in a short period of time. What should I do not to get this error anymore? It is still happening today.

